# Css and JS files doesn't minify and concatenate when use gulp-jade and gulp-useref

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pug, gulp-useref

I'm new with gulp and I'm trying to concatenate and minify my JS and CSS files. I'm using Jade.

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('jade2html', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
})

gulp.task('useref', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/*.jade')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```

**index.jade**

```
// build:css css/style.min.css
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/print.css')
// endbuild

// build:js js/main.min.js
script(src='js/lib/a-library.js')
script(src='js/lib/another-lib.js')
script(src='js/main.js')
// endbuild
```

When I run my task `useref` and then I check my `main.min.js` or `style.min.css` the files are empty. So, I'm missing some step? 
(When I don't use Jade and use just HTML everything works well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're piping Jade templates into `useref()`. However `gulp-useref` has no clue how to parse Jade. It only knows HTML.

That means you need to compile your Jade templates to HTML **before** you pipe them to `useref()`. Doing it in a separate task `jade2html` like you're trying to doesn't really work (at least not the way you're doing it). Besides you only really need one task to begin with:

```
gulp.task('useref', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/*.jade')
   .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
   .pipe(useref())
   .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
   .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```